# How to include 3rd party library referenced by another 3rd party library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using `netcoreapp2.0` as target framework in an ASP.NET Core 2 web app. I included a third-party library in the `.csproj` file as follows:

```
<ItemGroup>
<Reference Include="SomeLibrary64">
  <HintPath>SomeLibrary64.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

This compiles and runs without issue for most calls.

However, `SomeLibrary64` imports a c++ library for some functions and works fine when I place that second library in project root folder and run locally. When I deploy to server it fails with `500 error` since the second library is not part of the project.

Also, neither library is available as a NuGet package.

How do I include this second library in the project for deployment as a dependency?

Comment: is the other library compatible with the platform you are running on?

Comment: Yes, both dev and server machines have identical configurations: Win7.

Comment: Can't you copy the library to production server just like what you do in dev ?

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work, and it doesn't seem like that should be required. It must be possible to package it somehow. I also tried referencing it in the .csproj file, which also did not work.

Comment: Problem could be the PATH. Put c++ dll on path (like System32) and see what happens.

Comment: Dialecticus: Not sure what you mean. Both libraries are in the root folder (where program.cs is located). And, the goal here is to include the second, dependency, library as a project dependency.